# Find files with specific extension with recoll

Tags: files, recoll

How to make recoll program to show files with specific extension (for example, *.cpp, *.txt, etc)?

Comment: Hmmm....I don't understand your question.

Comment: @mdpc I'm not sure which part; he wants to do a text search with [recoll](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/), but only return files with the extensions he specifies

Comment: maybe I don't remember seeing a 'recoll' command in UNIX/Linux (thought it might be a mispelling)....

Comment: @MichaelMrozek You are right. I meant exactly what you have said.

Comment: Found solution here: [link](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/usermanual/rcl.search.lang.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use the Recoll query language. In the graphical version of Recoll, select "Query language" from the drop-down, and then use the `ext:` field specification. For example:

```
ext:cpp
```

will show `*.cpp` files, while

```
ext:txt
```

will show `*.txt` files.

You can also do this [from the command-line](https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/usermanual/webhelp/docs/RCL.SEARCH.COMMANDLINE.html) like this:

```
recoll -t -l 'ext:cpp' | less
```

> `ext` specifies the file name extension (Ex: `ext:html`)

https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/usermanual/webhelp/docs/RCL.SEARCH.LANG.html

Comment: http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/usermanual/usermanual.html (updated URL). Also I think just "recollq ext:cpp" works, no need for "include"?

Comment: @barrycarter Sorry, can't check it. I haven't used recoll for an year at least.